# iOS delegate issues with KVO

Tags: ios, facebook, delegates, key-value-observing

I have a method which sends out a request and has a delegate responder. The method is being called by a KVO responder. The code works fine when I call it from viewDidLoad, but when I make the request from the KVO method, it doesn't trigger the delegate method.

here is my KVO responder:

```
//observe app delegates userdata to check for when user data is available or data is changed
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"userData"] )
    {
        //goto facebook logic
        [self FBFriendSuggester];
    }
}
```

and the method it calls:

```
-(void)FBFriendSuggester
{
    NSDictionary * fb_credentials = nil;
    if([prefs objectForKey:@"facebookCredentials"])
    {
        fb_credentials = [prefs objectForKey:@"facebookCredentials"];
        if ([fb_credentials objectForKey:@"expiry"] && [fb_credentials objectForKey:@"fbtoken"]) {
            NSLog(@"found stored Facebook credentials.");
            ApplicationDelegate.facebook.accessToken = [fb_credentials objectForKey:@"fbtoken"];
            ApplicationDelegate.facebook.expirationDate = [fb_credentials objectForKey:@"expiry"];
        }
    }
    if ([ApplicationDelegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        printf("_valid facebook\n");
        [ApplicationDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
    }else
        printf("_invalid facebook\n");
}
```

and the delegate method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{
    NSLog(@"result2:%@",result);

    NSDictionary * rawObject = result;
    NSArray * dataArray = [rawObject objectForKey:@"data"];

    for (NSDictionary * f in dataArray) {
        [friends addObject:[[KNSelectorItem alloc] initWithDisplayValue:[f objectForKey:@"name"]
                                                            selectValue:[f objectForKey:@"id"]
                                                               imageUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=square", [f objectForKey:@"id"]]]];
    }
    [friends sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareByDisplayValue:)];
    [self pickerPopup:self];
}
```

the delegate method doesn't get called in this scenario, but it does work fine when i call -(void)FBFriendSuggester directly from the controller. I don't know what to do, i tried setting a notification to respond in hopes that it would trigger the delegate, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around my problem by issuing:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(FBFriendSuggester) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

It would be great to know why this works like this though.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is rather old, but to give a reason for this happening, KVO notifications are sent on the thread that the change occurs on.  So if a background thread makes a change to the property on the AppDelegate, the notification change will occur on the background thread as well.

So, in the context of your code, your `-(void)FBFriendSuggester` is most likely getting called in a background thread.  You could confirm this by tossing a breakpoint in the code and looking at the Debug Navigator.

I'll continue with the assumption that this was true (It was running in a background thread).

This call, `[ApplicationDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];` most likely needs to occur on the main thread.  Reason for this is probably the underlying calls are using an `NSURLConnection` to make the call.  The connections are made on background threads, but all delegate calls MUST be made back on the main thread, NOT a background thread.  With the call `andDelegate:self`, its registering the object as a delegate on the background thread, instead of the main thread.

This is why your current solution fixes that issue.

Happy Coding!